# IIS test GET on website link

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

I have 100 web servers and noticed that some of them have request filtering enabled for ".exe" extension. This means that if a user wants to access a .exe file with an application we ave it is blocked by the server.

Is there a way of doing any type of command line or script whereby I know which servers are affected? Currently I am testing by doing a manual check by going to internet explorer and typing in:

```
http://***SERVER1***/website/OFFICEPRO/2007/Office%20Professional/setup.exe

http://***SERVER2***/website/OFFICEPRO/2007/Office%20Professional/setup.exe
```

If I get a pop-up box stating to enter my credentials then that works. Hwoever if I get "Error Page (404)" then that does not work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use powershell to do this, the following should get you on your way:

```
$webClient = new-object Net.WebClient

gc servers.txt | Foreach-Object { 

    # send credentials to server
    $webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true;
    $url = "http://$_/website/OFFICEPRO/2007/Office%20Professional/setup.exe"
    try
    {
        $reult = $webClient.DownloadString($url)
        Write-host -fore Green $url "OK"
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException] 
    {
        Write-host -fore Red $url $_ 
    }
}
```

The file named servers.txt contains the list of servers you want to check.